# Initialization completed but access denied for Auto Scaling with Beanstalk service role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam

## Problem Overview

I'm trying to host my Express GraphQL API server on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Although the instance deployment completes successfully, I'm experiencing a couple of issues:

1. The environment health transitions from Pending to Warning shortly after initialization. I receive the following message: `Environment health has transitioned from Pending to Warning. Initialization completed 8 seconds ago and took 88 seconds. Access denied while accessing Auto Scaling using role "arn:aws:iam::11211472349863:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role". Verify the role policy.`
2. My application is supposed to return a JSON response {code: 200} when it is working correctly. However, instead, I'm getting a `502 Bad Gateway` error.

The environment health transitions from Pending to Warning shortly after initialization. I receive the following message:

[image]

My project runs without issues on my local machine.

### Project Configuration

The relevant sections of my package.json file are as follows:

```json
...
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./dist/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon ./dist/index.js"
  },  
...
```

### AWS IAM Role Configuration

I've assigned permissions to the role, as depicted in the following screenshot:

[image]

#### Trust Relationships

The trust relationship for the IAM role is defined as shown in this code:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please assist me in resolving this warning and successfully deploying my Express GraphQL API server to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: The service role should be assume by Elastic Beanstalk service not EC2, this detail answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77743069/12326605

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

### 1. Attach a policy to your IAM role

You can reference this: [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts-roles.html).

[image]

### 2. Go to Security Group on EC2 to Edit inbound rule (Optional)

Select the Security Group associated with your Beanstalk project and configure it to allow traffic on the port specified in your app.

[image]